# CSS Styling Not Applied on iPhone 11 When Accessing Deployed Create-React-App

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, netlify

I have created a Create React App and styled it using CSS. The CSS file containing the styling is named App.css and is located in the folder NameOfTheApp/src/App.css. The content of the CSS file looks like this:

```
.toShopMainContent {
  .toShopAddItemSegment {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;

    .toShopAddItemExpander {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;

      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;

      .chevron {
        height: 25px;
        margin-left: 5px;
      }
    }

    .toShopAddItemWrapper {
      display: none;
      background-color: white;

      &.expanded {
        display: block;
      }

      .toShopAddItem {
        padding: 7px;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 2px;

        .itemInput {
          &:first-child {
            width: 70px;
          }
          padding: 5px;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 10px;
          background-color: #f0f0f0;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .addIcon {
          height: 25px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .toShopRow {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 5px;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

    .deleteIcon {
      height: 33px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, there is an index.html file located in NameOfTheApp/public/index.html. The content of this file is as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand&family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I have deployed this Create React App using Netlify. When I visit the website on my computer, everything looks great, and all CSS classes are being applied. However, the problem arises when I access the site via my iPhone 11 using Chrome or Safari browsers. None of the CSS classes seem to be applied. Can anyone help me identify and troubleshoot this issue?